# Django Datatables

Tags: javascript, python, django

Soy nuevo en Django y estoy usando `datatables.net`.

Tengo una tabla con unos 13,000 registros y el problema que tengo es que al momento de ejecutar la plantilla me empieza a mostrar los datos con el formato de la tabla nativa de **Django** y veo como que se va reajustando el tamaño mientras continúa cargando los datos.

Luego de cargar todos los datos (aprox unos 20 seg) me muestra la tabla con el formato de `datatables.net`. Después funciona perfecto y puedo paginar, buscar, ordenar y etc.

La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que no muestre la tabla de **Django** mientras carga los datos? y si se puede acelerar el proceso para que muestre los 10 primeros sin esperar los 20 seg.
Estuve leyendo de procesar en el server pero realmente no entiendo como hacerlo

Agradecería si alguien me puede facilitar algún código de ejemplo, Gracias.

Archivo `prutable.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Tabla!</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
</head>    
<body>    
    <table id="table_id" class="display" border='2' align="center" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>    
            {% for articulo in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ articulo.cdg }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.imp }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.stock }}</td>
            </tr>    
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>        
</body>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({    
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class LstPreListView(ListView):
    template_name = "base/prutable.html"
    queryset = Articulo.objects.all().order_by("desc")
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):   
    cdg = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, blank=True, null=False)
    desc = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    imp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} '.format(self.nombre)
```

Comment: Una posible solución tu pregunta de: *"se puede acelerar el proceso para que muestre los 10 primeros sin esperar los 20seg?"*, pues puedes utilizar [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/), que ayuda a administrar datos paginados, es decir, datos que se dividen en varias páginas, con enlaces "Anterior / Siguiente", podrás mostrar **x** registros en **x** paginas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Julio. El tema del paginado lo habia hecho pero lo descarte por las funcionalidades del datatables como la busqueda y ordenamiento.

Comment: De hecho utilizar el *Paginator* no afecta o interfiere con las funcionalidades de datatables, lo que hace el *Paginator* es, en base al valor del parámetro GET "page" (que indica la pagina), actualiza el `object_list` con la lista de objetos de la respectiva pagina, prácticamente solo cambia  o se actualiza, la variable de contexto que se esta iterando. Te debería funcionar sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que en la arquitectura de Django, los templates son "interpretados", e incluso "generados" por Django, es decir, primero tu código pasa por el Template Engine de Django antes de ser ejecutado. Esa es la razón por la que primero vez la tabla de Django y después la tabla de DataTables.

Para evitar esto, puedes probar cargar jQuery y el JS de DataTable en el `<head>` del HTML, después de tu CSS.

Comment: Gracias Diego. Probé lo que dices y me sigue haciendo lo mismo. Mi pregunta es como hacen para manejar grandes bases de datos y permitir la búsqueda. Ej: Si quiero consultar una base de artículos y esta tiene 30.000 registros me imagino que se podrá mostrar una grilla para buscar sin tener que esperar 40seg a cargar todos los datos